# MAMP asking to install wordpress after I deleted files from /db/mysql56

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, mamp

after mysql wouldn't start, I searched, and found some advice, after following said advice, I deleted files in MAMP/db/mysql56 (not folders).

This solved the problem of mysql not loading. BUT... it now asks me to install wordpress again. Even if I try to do that, it won't let me. I get errors saying the database doesn't exist etc.

Does anyone know of anything I can try now to get the local site back up and running?

thanks so much!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You just deleted the whole MySQL database of MAMP.. thats your problem. Restore the files and debug further why MySQL is not starting. What you did can not fix the problem you are having. If you don't have a backup of those files consider your database lost and completely remove MAMP and reinstall to start over.